# How to configure cas server to forward service ticket to another server for federation

Tags: service, jwt, cas

I have configured the cas server to communicate with a cas client application by cas protocol and the service ticket is in form of jwt token. I want to make the cas server be able to forward this ticket to a server outside, for example the server which running my own ticket handler instead of the server running the cas client. Is there any possibility to achieve this in a good manner?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any possibility to achieve this in a good manner?

Absolutely not, and this is not a good idea at all. You either need to use proxy tickets, or a proper application of something like OIDC and a relevant profile. Anything else likely is a spaghetti and will lead to a broken implementation.